# ThreeJS & Fragment Shader Window Size

Tags: opengl-es, 3d, three.js, webgl, particle-system

In my ThreeJS `WebGLRenderer` scene, I am currently clipping pixels with a GLSL fragment (pixel) shader, according to their distance from the lower left-hand corner of the screen:

```
if (distance(vec2(gl_FragCoord.x, gl_FragCoord.y), vec2(0.0, 0.0)) > 42.0)
    discard;
```

This shader is used with a `ThreeJS.ShaderMaterial` instance, that ends up used with a `PointCloud` mesh, that ends up a particle system in the scene.

My question is, how do I determine the "window size" for this shader? I am happy to pass these pixel dimensions from ThreeJS to the shader, but do not know the best way to map a ThreeJS geometry & mesh to a GLSL window size. Passing in `window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight` does not work.

The goal is to clip fragments that are near the center of the physical screen:

```
if (distance(vec2(gl_FragCoord.x, gl_FragCoord.y), vec2(pixelWidth * 0.5, pixelHeight * 0.5)) > 42.0)
    discard;
```

How would I find `pixelWidth` and `pixelHeight` on the ThreeJS side?

Comment: `attribute` is inappropriate for the fragment shader. Something qualified as `attribute` is a vertex attribute. In a fragment shader, the equivalent of a per-vertex attribute is a `varying`. But I don't think you want that - you'd have to write this attribute once for every vertex. A `uniform` is probably what you want.

Answer (score 2):

If you're rendering to the canvas you can get the actual size with

```
var width = renderer.context.drawingBufferWidth;
var height = renderer.context.drawingBufferHeight;
```

If you're rendering to a render target then

```
var width = renderTarget.width;
var height = renderTarget.height;
```

should work

Comment: Thank you for the help, @gman. And for addressing the actual question, rather than nitpicking.

You got me in the right direction. In my case, I needed to do:

    var width = webGLRenderer.context.drawingBufferWidth;
    var height = webGLRenderer.context.drawingBufferHeight;

And then pass those values into the shader. Thanks again!

Comment: Assuming you're talking about the comment on your question, it *is* strange to see you passing in `pixelWidth` and `pixelHeight` as attributes :D  Unless you really meant to do that maybe you want to edit your question so others don't copy that example?

Comment: Good point. I removed attribute (or varying or uniform) references, since how state is passed from ThreeJS into shaders is not relevant to the question.